# Basic Authentication in wildfly server behind a AWS ALB loadbalancer not Working

Tags: wildfly, basic-authentication, aws-application-load-balancer

I'm trying to deploy a Basic Authentication method for our REST Service API and same works perfectly when running on local device, but I'm facing issues when the Server sits behind AWS Application Loadbalancer (ALB). The user cannot authenticate when the wildly is running behind the ALB.

I've already tried to set the sticky session on the ALB, but the issue is still not resolved.

Appreciate if someone can advise.

Wildfly version is 25.0.0 using Elytron Security.

jboss-web.xml--------------------------------------------------------------------

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <jboss-web version="8.0" xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.org/schema/jbossas http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/schema/jbossas/jboss-web_8_0.xsd">     <context-root>/kycVerification</context-root>     <security-domain flushOnSessionInvalidation="true">kyc</security-domain>     <security-domain flushOnSessionInvalidation="true">kycApi</security-domain> </jboss-web>`

web.xml---------------------------------------------------------------------------
`


javax.ws.rs.core.Application
1

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
    <session-timeout>5</session-timeout>
    <cookie-config>
        <name>__Securepg</name>
        <http-only>true</http-only>
        <secure>true</secure>
    </cookie-config>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>rest</web-resource-name>
        <description>Security KycClientGatewayApi</description>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
        <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
        <http-method>CONNECT</http-method>
        <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>WEB-INF</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>kycApi</realm-name>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <role-name>APIUSER</role-name>
</security-role>
```

`